# Flows in signed graphs and coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, signed-graphs

Nowhere-zero flows and coloring of planar graphs are related by duality. [(wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere-zero_flow#Flow.2Fcoloring_duality) I heard that there was a similar relation for nowhere-zero flows in signed graphs and colorings of some other graphs. I can't seem to find it. Can somebody say what the relation is and maybe also explain it?

Comment: I do not recall seeing any duality type relation between flows and colourings in general graphs.

Comment: Sorry, I see that I left out an important word: edited!

Comment: I think you might be referring to colourings of graphs embedded in the projective plane.

Comment: Yes, I think that was it: embedded in the projective plasne.